# Continuous function on $\mathcal{X}(M)$ which is only 0 for topologically equivalent VFs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and we are given two VFs $F,F' \in \mathcal{X}(M)$. We define a DS by
$$\dot{x}=F(x)$$
and equivalently for $F'$.

The two vector fields are topologically equivalent , denoted by $F \simeq F' \, $ if there exists a homeomorphism $h: U \rightarrow U$, mapping orbits of the first system onto
orbits of the second system, i.e.
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \ \forall x \in U: \quad \phi^{F}_t(x)=h^{-1} \circ \phi^{F'}_{\tau} \circ h(x),$$
with $ \tau: U \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \frac{\partial \tau(x,t)}{\partial t} >0 \quad \forall x \in U $. This means the time direction of the orbits is preserved.

We make $\mathcal{X}(M)$ a topological space by using the $\mathcal{C}^1$-induced topology.

---

**My question is the following:** Can we define a function
$$g: \mathcal{X}(M) \times \mathcal{X}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
which is continuous in the $\mathcal{C}^1$ induced topology and 0 if and only if the two VFs are topologically equivalent, i.e.
$$ g(F,F')=0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad F \simeq F'$$

Comment: Follow up to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759817/are-vector-fields-topologically-equivalent-when-their-limitings-sets-coincide/4759852#4759852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such function $g$ exists in general, and in fact the answer I gave to your previous question can be used to produce a counterexample.

In that answer I gave an example of a family of flows $\phi_r$ on the torus $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$, defined for all $r \in \mathbb R \cup \infty$. If we think of $\mathbb R \cup \infty \approx S^1$, and if we define the vector field $F_r$ so that the flow $\phi_r$ that it generates is a unit speed flow on $T^2$ (i.e. if we define $F_r$ so that all its vectors have length $1$), then this family $F_r$ is continuous in the $C^1$ induced topology. And as mentioned in that answer, $F_r$ and $F_s$ are topologically equivalent if and only if the numbers $r,s$ are in the same orbit as the action of the group $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ --- which, by definition, means that there exists a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ with integer coefficients such that $ad-bc=1$ and such that $r=\frac{as+b}{cs+d}$.

However, each orbit of the action of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$. So for any ordered pair $(t,u) \in (\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\})^2$, there exists a sequence of ordered pairs $(r_n,s_n)$ such that the entire set $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} \{r_n,s_n\}$ is in a single orbit of the $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ action, and such that $\lim r_n = t$ and $\lim s_n = u$. So if $g$ is continuous in the $C^1$ induced topology and is zero whenever $F_r,F_s$ are topologically equivalent, it follows that $g(r_n,s_n)=0$. By continuity of $g$ it follows that $g(t,u)=0$. So $g$ cannot distinguish when $F_t$, $F_u$ are topologically inequivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to be a 100% sure. By $r_n$ you construct a series in $\mathbb{R}$ which is dense, since it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ but both converge to a different irrational number making the associated flow not topological equivalent in the limit. But along the series they are topological equivalent because they are in the same orbit?

Comment: I construct not just one sequence $r_n$, but also another sequence $s_n$. *All* of the points $r_1,r_2,r_3,...,s_1,s_2,s_3,...$ are in the same orbit, but the sequence $(r_n)$ converges to $t$, whereas the sequence $(s_n)$ converges to $u$. This is possible because, as said, each orbit of the action of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$. This has nothing to do with being *homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$*. It's a special fact about the action of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, based on the theory of continued fractions.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here, coming from the theory of continued fractions and its connection with $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$. But rather than try to give you all the details of proof within that theory, I've written my answer to just give the statements of that theory and their applications.

Comment: The real takeaway here is that these examples on $T^2$ are basic and well known (see e.g. the Katok-Hasselblatt book), and once you have mastered them they give a reasonably straightforward counterexample to your posted question.